# Implementing UART driver with Interrupts and DMA - UART_RXC ISR is executed only first time a character is received

Tags: microcontroller, avr, avr-gcc, atxmega

I am using ATxMega 32E5 and my current task is to rewrite existing RS485 driver and use DMA to save in my case
valuable cycles (the speed is going to be multiplied by 8x going from 230k to 2M baudrate).
So naturaly I have been experimenting with single design that I iteratively reduced to
minimal example shown below.

Let me explain what I am trying to accomplish. We have defined proprietary
protocol (slighty similar to modbus) and I have already implemented it using interrupts.
This simplified version however is trying to do only the following:

1. Wait for a character in RXC ISR and read it
2. Disable interrupts for RXC by setting the interrupt priority to *0b00*
3. Set-up DMA to receive one character
4. Wait until the DMA finishes
5. Set interrupt priority for RXC to *0b10*, disable and re-enable reception
6. repeat from 1.

The code is below (I am testing it with 230.400k baudrate at 32MHz mcu, you can skip the initialization - it should be OK since it worked well with previous interrupt-based design).

```
#define RS_PRIORITY_RXC USART_RXCINTLVL_HI_gc

void rs_init() {
    // Enable Transmit Complete Interrupt
    USARTD0.CTRLA = RS_PRIORITY_TXC;

    PORTD.REMAP = 1<<4; // Remap usart from 2,3 to 6,7
    PORTD.DIRSET = 1<<7;
    PORTD.OUTSET = 1<<7; //set TX high
    PORTD.OUTCLR = 1<<5; // DIR low = input
    USARTD0.CTRLB = 0b11100; //enable TX and RX, 2X speed
    USARTD0.CTRLC = 0b011; //no parity, async, 8bit, 1 stop bit

  // Sets-up 230.400k baud rate
    USARTD0.BAUDCTRLA = RS_BAUDCTRL & 0xff; // BSEL lo
    USARTD0.BAUDCTRLB = ((RS_BAUDSCALE & 0xf) << 4) | ((RS_BAUDCTRL >> 8) & 0xf); //BSCALE:7-4, BSEL:3-0

    // Enable Receive Complete interrupt
    USARTD0.CTRLA |= RS_PRIORITY_RXC;

    // Initialize EDMA - this is needed for SPI and RS485
    EDMA.CTRL = (1<<6); // reset
    EDMA.CTRL = (1<<7) | 0b0000; // enable, no double buffering, four perip chan

    // CH0 is for RS485 RX, CH2 for TX
    // CH1 is for SPI TX, CH3 for RX
    EDMA.CH1.CTRLA = EDMA.CH0.CTRLA = 1<<6; // reset
    EDMA.CH3.CTRLA = EDMA.CH2.CTRLA = 1<<6; // reset

}

struct {
  char buffer[128];
} state;

static void setup_rx_dma(uint8_t len) {
    // USARTD0.CTRLA &= ~RS_PRIORITY_RXC;
    // volatile uint32_t reg __attribute__((__unused__));
    // reg = USARTD0.DATA;

    EDMA.CH0.CTRLB = 0b1010; // set medium interrupt levels
    EDMA.CH0.ADDRCTRL = 0b001; // none reload, incremental transfer peripheral to memory
    EDMA.CH0.TRIGSRC = EDMA_CH_TRIGSRC_USARTD0_RXC_gc;
    EDMA.CH0.TRFCNT = len;
    EDMA.CH0.ADDR = (register16_t) state.buffer;
    EDMA.CH0.CTRLA = (1<<7) /* enable */ | (1<<2) /* single shot mode */;
}

static inline void dontExpect(uint8_t *expr, uint8_t exp_value, uint16_t delay) {
    if(*expr == exp_value) {
        while(1) {
            led_toggle();
            rtc_delay_ms(delay);
        }
    }
    *expr = exp_value;
}

static uint8_t _state = 0;

ISR(EDMA_CH0_vect) {
    led_disable();
    // Check
    dontExpect(&_state, 0, 100);


    // Disable reception of frames
    USARTD0.CTRLB &= ~USART_RXEN_bm;
    // Set RXC interrupt from 0b00 to 0b10
    USARTD0.CTRLA |= RS_PRIORITY_RXC;
    // Enable reception of frames
    USARTD0.CTRLB |= USART_RXEN_bm;

    // Reset DMA
    EDMA.CH0.CTRLA = (1<<6) /* reset */;
}


ISR(USARTD0_RXC_vect) {
    led_enable();
    // Check 
    dontExpect(&_state, 1, 500);

    // Read the received character
    volatile uint32_t reg __attribute__((__unused__));
    reg = USARTD0.DATA;

    // Disable RXC interrupts by setting interrupt priority from 0b10 to 0b00
    USARTD0.CTRLA &= ~RS_PRIORITY_RXC;

    // Start DMA transfer for 1 byte
    setup_rx_dma(1);
}
```

What happens however is that it blinks only once (very fast blink) and then it remains
off and the mcu does nothing - I re-enable the interrupts in DMA_CH0 ISR, but it has no
effect since the LED remains off which means that RXC is called only once first and
last time when a byte is received.

I have tested the DMA code on its own and it successfully received however many bytes I wanted. But together the Interrupts + DMA do not work.

Does someone
know why is this not working? Meaning how can I propertly enable RXC interrupt
from DMA_CH0 ISR so that RXC gets called successfully again and again when it has to?
I am sorry, but I have spent way too much time debugging this driver and
I can't even write working minimal example code.

Comment: I'm not sure how your plan to receive one byte by Interrupt, then one byte by DMA, and then repeating actually saves you any significant amount of CPU cycles... Is the 1-byte DMA only a temporary measure which you plan to increase in future (maybe the 1st byte you get by IRQ tells you how many bytes to DMA)?

Comment: @brhans sure, otherwise it would be waste of time. This is just for testing purposes, in real scenario the DMA will read around 40-120 bytes. This is just a short test code that I can't get to work, in fact the second byte is length but we don't care about it yet. This will be solved using switch(state) {case}, but not before I get this short code to work.